# Netsuite SQL Query to find all the open invoice

Tags: netsuite

I am new to netsuite.

I am having the following scenario,

Fetch all the open invoice based on the Period in NetSuite using Query.

Eg: I am having an period "Mar 2021". It should fetch all the invoice opened on march 2021.(Scope: Its should show the invoice that is closed on April 2021, because that invoice is Open on March)

Sample Code:

```
select
  t.*
from
  Transaction t
  INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl ON (tl.Transaction = t.ID)
  INNER JOIN Subsidiary sb ON sb.id = tl.subsidiary
  INNER JOIN AccountingPeriod ap ON (
    (ap.id = t.postingperiod)
    AND ap.isposting = 'T'
  )
  INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr1 ON (
    cr1.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
    AND cr1.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
    AND (
      cr1.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
  )
  INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr2 ON (
    cr2.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
    AND cr2.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
    AND (
      cr2.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
  )
  LEFT JOIN CurrencyRate cr3 ON (
    cr3.BaseCurrency = 1
    AND cr3.TransactionCurrency = sb.currency
    AND (
      cr3.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(t.TranDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    )
  )
  INNER JOIN consolidatedexchangerate cexr ON (
    cexr.postingperiod = t.PostingPeriod
    AND cexr.fromsubsidiary = tl.subsidiary
    AND cexr.tosubsidiary = 1
  )
Where
  ((t.AbbrevType in ('BILL', 'INV')))
  AND (tl.MainLine = 'T')
  AND (tl.subsidiary IN (1))
  AND (
    t.postingperiod BETWEEN (mar 2020)
    AND (mar 2020)
  )
```

The above code shows all invoice and bills,
Issue with the above code : It is not showing the transaction (#121) if its closed on posting period Apr 2020. (It need to show the transaction #121,because it is opened in Mar 2020 and only closed in APR 2020)

Is there any way to archive this in NetSuite query,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data, table description, what have you tried, expected result and what `MySQL` version are you using. https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: SELECT * FROM SYSTEM_NOTES WHERE TRANSACTION_ID=XXXXX  here you can see when the status changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no analytics tables that you can use that will tell you the status of an invoice on a particular date.  The best approximation that you can get is using something trying to find the `trandate` of the transaction that closed the bill or invoice (e.g., a vendor payment or customer payment).

This will the trandate on the customer payment will let you know if a transaction had been created at a time within the march period, but the closing transaction posted in another accounting period.